# Как сделать поочередное нажатие клавиш?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я хочу, чтобы, к примеру, при нажатие клавиши `Esc` и затем клавиши `a` происходило действие (например, открытие канваса) или так, чтобы сначала любую из этих клавиш нажать, а потом вторую.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый примитивный пример.
Контракт:

```
namespace KeyCombinations
{
    public interface IKeyInput
    {
        bool Performed { get; }
    }
}
```

Комбинация:

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace KeyCombinations
{
    public class KeyCombination : IKeyInput
    {
        private readonly KeyCode _first;
        private readonly KeyCode _second;

        public KeyCombination(KeyCode first, KeyCode second)
        {
            _first = first;
            _second = second;
        }

        public bool Performed => (Input.GetKey(_first) && Input.GetKeyDown(_second));
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace KeyCombinations
{
    public class Test : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private readonly IKeyInput _keyInput = new KeyCombination(KeyCode.LeftShift, KeyCode.F);

        private void Update()
        {
            if (_keyInput.Performed)
            {
                Debug.Log("Combination performed");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Если нужно, чтобы отображалось в инспекторе:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

namespace KeyCombinations
{
    [Serializable]
    public class KeyCombination : IKeyInput
    {
        [SerializeField] private KeyCode _first;
        [SerializeField] private KeyCode _second;

        public KeyCombination(KeyCode first, KeyCode second)
        {
            _first = first;
            _second = second;
        }

        public bool Performed => (Input.GetKey(_first) && Input.GetKeyDown(_second));
    }
}
```

```cs
using UnityEngine;

namespace KeyCombinations
{
    public class Test : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private KeyCombination _keyInput;

        private void Update()
        {
            if (_keyInput.Performed)
            {
                Debug.Log("Combination performed");
            }
        }
    }
}
```